# You don't have permission to access file on this server

Tags: ubuntu, drupal, permissions, server, http-status-code-403

I have a Drupal-server (UBUNTU) with Drupal 8 running on it. If i place some php-file in my root-directory i can run them in my browser but when i place the same file in a sub-directory the browser gave a 403 Forbidden-error. 
I have already changed the permissions to 777 but it isn't working.

Can anybody help me?

> "Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access myfile on this server.
>   Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at 192.168.51.60 Port 80"

Comment: Try allowing access to all parent dirs as well all up to the web root dir.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how exactly is your server set up and in which folder is the .php file located, but Drupal installation by default contains .htaccess file which defines various rules limiting which files and folders are accessible on an apache http server.
Check your .htaccess file for this section:

```
# For security reasons, deny access to other PHP files on public sites.
# Note: The following URI conditions are not anchored at the start (^),
# because Drupal may be located in a subdirectory. To further improve
# security, you can replace '!/' with '!^/'.
# Allow access to PHP files in /core (like authorize.php or install.php):
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/core/[^/]*\.php$
# Allow access to test-specific PHP files:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/core/modules/system/tests/https?.php
# Allow access to Statistics module's custom front controller.
# Copy and adapt this rule to directly execute PHP files in contributed or
# custom modules or to run another PHP application in the same directory.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/core/modules/statistics/statistics.php$
# Deny access to any other PHP files that do not match the rules above.
# Specifically, disallow autoload.php from being served directly.
RewriteRule "^(.+/.*|autoload)\.php($|/)" - [F]
```

Comment: Specifically the last line with the autoload is preventing access to any other non-drupal paths on the site.

This comment on Drupal.org has a solution, which I will paste here: https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/post-installation/2017-02-07/d8-unable-to-run-custom-php-script-within-drupal#comment-12510434

You will need to add a line above the autload line with your custom directory:  
  
`# Allow for my_custom_directory folder to run php`    
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/my_custom_directory/[^/]*\.php$`

Apologies for formatting this is my first ever comment.